# How can I embed R console in a web page?

Tags: r, web, embed, interactive

I am planning to create interactive R tutorials for my students like Datacamp or Codecademy. (Actually Datacamp is very good but some of my students' English level is not enough so I want to write tutorials in my own language.)

How can I create interactive R tutorials like the ones in Datacamp? i.e. embed an R console to the webpage, where students can answer questions, do the exercises and follow up their progresses.

ps. There is the R package **learnr** by RStudio but I need to subscribe to R Connect, shinyapps etc. and that exceeds my budget.

Comment: You might want to try Googling your question first next time: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#R-Web-Interfaces

Comment: Thanks but of course I saw this link before. Most of the links there doesn't work. So, some constructive response please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the same app of datacamp, you can download from Github.
https://github.com/datacamp/tutorial

You can check how with they help
https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/create-your-own-r-tutorials-with-github-datacamp